# I am having an issue with leaving macarons to form a skin

Tags: baking, macarons

I have a few macaron orders, so I need to bake them. However, when it is raining and the air is moist they don't form a skin very well. What can I do to make sure they form a skin before they go in the oven when there is moisture in the air?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The need to leave macarons to form a skin is debatable, but if you feel it's necessary, put them uncovered in the fridge, which will dry them out nicely. Be careful that there's nothing else in there with a strong smell that may taint the macarons, however.